# What does the Twilio statusCallback file look like?

Tags: twilio

I am sending a voice message via Twilio and specifying a callback url for all the statuses but I don't think it is actually getting called because I have not been able to find out what the call back file is supposed to look like. What does the callback file look for? Is it a form being sent in? What does my "callbackfilename" code look like? I cannot find that info anywhere. thanks

These are my params:

```
 params["StatusCallback"]= "http://XXXX.com/events/callbackfilename";
 params["StatusCallbackMethod"]="POST";
 params["StatusCallbackEvent"]="initiated"; 
 params["StatusCallbackEvent"]="ringing";
 params["StatusCallbackEvent"]="answered"; 
 params["StatusCallbackEvent"]="completed"; 
 params["IfMachine"] = "Continue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The StatusCallback comes much the same as a TwiML request for an incoming calls. It's sent as form encoded data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) and includes all [the regular parameters sent in an incoming call request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request).

You also get a [bunch of bonus parameters, listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter). You can see those parameters below too:

```
CallStatus          A descriptive status for the call. The value is one of queued, initiated, ringing, in-progress, busy, failed, or no-answer. See the CallStatus section for more details.
CallDuration        The duration in seconds of the just-completed call. Only present in the completed event.
RecordingUrl        The URL of the phone call's recorded audio. This parameter is included only if Record=true is set on the REST API request and does not include recordings from <Dial> or <Record>. RecordingUrl is only present in the completed event.
RecordingSid        The unique ID of the Recording from this call. RecordingSid is only present in the completed event.
RecordingDuration   The duration of the recorded audio (in seconds). RecordingDuration is only present in the completed event.
Timestamp           The timestamp when the event was fired, given as UTC in RFC 2822 format.
CallbackSource      A string that describes the source of the webhook. This is provided to help disambiguate why the webhook was made. On Status Callbacks, this value is always call-progress-events.
SequenceNumber      The order in which the events were fired, starting from 0. Although events are fired in order, they are made as separate HTTP requests and there is no guarantee they will arrive in the same order.
```

If you want to check these parameters and that they're getting sent, you could set up something like a [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) which records the requests so that you can inspect them easily.

Let me know if this helps.